# Only able to play audio in video file recorded video using Kurento Media Server and WebRTC from my iPhone to local server machine

Tags: swift, xcode, webrtc, video-recording, kurento

I am trying to record the video from my iPhone and Android device. I am using Kurento media server and WebRTC to achieve this. I am able to record the video in my local server machine with extension of .webm formate.
**Problem-**
When trying to play recorded video then audio is getting played properly but video frames is not moving.
*video detail is*

```
Input #0,matroska,webm,from'recorder__xC5OtoECP5zMM_5AAAG.webm':Metadata:
encoder         : GStreamer matroskamux version 1.8.1.1
creation_time   : 2017-10-18T09:27:47.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:21.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 403 kb/s
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 480x640, SAR 1:1 DAR
3:4, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
Metadata:
title           : Video
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
Metadata:
title           : Audio
```

Same server implementation is working fine with android.
*What could be the problem in video data?*

Comment: Did you solve it? I encounter the same issue. the video from android work well, but   the video from iOS only has audio.